# How Looping works with line break in FPDF in PHP?

Tags: php, fpdf

I am working on making a PDF document through php, but in my for loop everything is printing in same line rather than in next line,

Here is my code -

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_GET);$i++){
    if(trim($_GET[$i])!="") {
        $printQueryResult = runPrintQuery($_GET[$i]);
        $totalRows = mysql_num_rows($printQueryResult);
        $resultArrayIndex = mysql_fetch_array($printQueryResult);

        //Headline of index
        $pdf->setXY(40, 41);
        $pdf->SetFillColor(238, 236, 225);
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 8);
        $pdf->Cell(25, 6, formatPubDate($resultArrayIndex['title']), 0, 0, 'L', True);
    }
}
```

Here is my output

[image: Wrong Output]

and here what i am trying to achieve

[image: Correct one]

each text in a new line.

Comment: You're setting the same X and Y location every time through the loop.

Comment: Warning: The `mysql` extension has been deprecated for years, and has been removed completely in PHP 7.0. You should have upgraded a long time ago.

Comment: You should increment the `Y` value each time through the loop.

Comment: 5th parameter of Cell() controls line break. Of course, if you force the location with SetXY(), it will be useless.

Comment: @Barmar could you please give any  example?

Comment: Something like `$pdf->setXY(40, 41 + 20 * i);`. Adjust the multiplier until you get the desired spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$pdf->setXY(40, 41); // put this line outside loop
for($i=0;$i<count($_GET);$i++){
    if(trim($_GET[$i])!="") {
        $printQueryResult = runPrintQuery($_GET[$i]);
        $totalRows = mysql_num_rows($printQueryResult);
        $resultArrayIndex = mysql_fetch_array($printQueryResult);
        //Headline of index
        $pdf->SetFillColor(238, 236, 225);
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 8);
        $pdf->Cell(25, 6, formatPubDate($resultArrayIndex['title']), 0, 0, 'L', True);
        $pdf->Ln(); // aply new line
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @benilson can we do word wrap also in it?

Comment: Use `$pdf->Ln();`.

Comment: with $pdf -> Ln(); word can be wrap? within cell?